# Is memory barrier related to some specific memory location?

Tags: concurrency, memory-model

I'm trying to learn the basics about low-level concurrency.

From Linux documentation:

```
 A write memory barrier gives a guarantee that all the STORE operations
 specified before the barrier will appear to happen before all the STORE
 operations specified after the barrier with respect to the other
 components of the system.
```

I think that "all the STORE operations" must mean that there are more instances of a particular barrier type than one and there is probably `1:N` relationship between a barrier instance and a STORE. Where can I find confirmation for this?

Comment: It means that there will not be any reordering of writing operations that are not visible to read operations after the store barrier. Have a look at the cookbook for the Java memory model where such barriers are mapped to simple code examples, maybe it helps: http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html

Answer (score 1):

Memory barriers are not related to any specific memory locations.

It's not about "write to memory address x should happen before write to address y", it's about execution order of instructions, e.g. for program

```
x = 2
y = 1
```

processor may decide: "I don't want to wait until 2 will be finally stored in x, I can start writing 1 to y while `x = 2` is still in progress" (also known as out-of-order execution/reordering), so reader on another core may observe 0 in x (its initial value) after observing 1 in y which is counter-intuitive behaviour.

If you place write barrier between two stores, then reader can be sure that if he observes results of second store, the first one is also happened, so if he reads y == 1, then it's known that x == 2 (It's not that easy though, because reads can be executed out of order too, so you need read barrier). In other words, such barrier forbids executing `y = 1` while `x = 2` is not finished.

As @RafaelWinterhalter mentioned, there is [awesome guide](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) for JVM compiler writers, which has many concrete examples how barriers are mapped to real code.

As additional reading see Preshing blog, it has many articles about low level concurrency, e.g. [this one about barriers](http://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/).